# How can I edit my specialties on Linkedin?

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm trying to find a way to change the listing specialities I have on LinkedIn, but can't find any way to do so.  Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. webapps.stackexchange.com would be a more appropriate site for this question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The specialties has been replaced by skills. You can add/edit skills from your Profile, click  `Add profile section` and you will find the skills in the dropdown menu.

Comment: Ah... right so no more specialities.  That makes it all much clearer @cgl